# captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body

Tags: rust

I want to mutably iterate over two elements in a struct but I get an error. Here is the simplified code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Attr {
    value1: usize,
    value2: Vec<usize>
}

impl Default for Attr {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { 
            value1: 100,
            value2: vec![1;1000],
        }
    }
}


struct Data {
    inner: Vec<usize>, //A complex structure in real code
    attrs: HashMap<usize, Attr>,
}


fn iter_data(d: &mut Data) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, &mut Attr)> {
    d.inner.iter().map(|x| (*x, d.attrs.get_mut(x).unwrap()))
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = Data {
        inner: Vec::new(),
        attrs: HashMap::new()
    };
    
    for i in 1..100 { 
        data.inner.push(i);
        data.attrs.insert(i, Default::default());
    }

   for (k, v) in iter_data(&mut data){ // mutably iterate data
  
   }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src/main.rs:25:28
   |
24 | fn iter_data(d: &mut Data) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, &mut Attr)> {
   |              - variable defined here
25 |     d.inner.iter().map(|x| (*x, d.attrs.get_mut(x).unwrap()))
   |                          - ^^^^^-^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                          | |    |
   |                          | |    variable captured here
   |                          | returns a reference to a captured variable which escapes the closure body
   |                          inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

I want to know how to avoid this error? I just want to iterate each element in `Data` and modify the `attrs` of each element. I know I can iterate `attrs` with `(key, value)` directly, but there are some problems in the real code.

Comment: You can pass a closuce to the `iter_data()` function to change the values, instead of returning an iterator.

Comment: It looks like what you want is [`IndexMap`](https://docs.rs/indexmap/latest/indexmap/map/struct.IndexMap.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `fn iter_data(d: &mut Data) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, &mut Attr)>` as shown can't work that way for fundamental reasons. Besides the actual implementation in Rust which prevents this problem, consider the case where `inner: Vec<usize>` contains the values `vec![0, 0]`, and I'd call

```rust
let bar = iter_data(&mut foo).collect::<Vec<(usize, &mut Attr)>>();
```

The way `iter_data()` is currently written says that `bar` now has to contain two `&mut`-references to the same `Attr` (`vec![(0, &mut Attr), (0, &mut Attr)]`). That can't be, and the compiler can't statically prove that this won't happen.

There are two ways out of this:

- Use interior mutability, that is, a `RefCell` to mutably borrow `data`. This allows the closure to immutably capture `data`, downgrading the `FnMut` to a `Fn`. This also would cause the cooked-up example above to `panic!()` at runtime when the `Iterator` is in fact `collect()`ed, or through any other means a second `&mut` to the same `Attr` was about to come into existence.
- Use interior iteration, that is, redesign `iter_data()` to take a closure that gets executed for every item. This allows you to *not* return references to the caller at all, which eases the compiler's need of proving that those references do not escape.

I'd recommend the second approach. As a general rule of thumb: When dealing with `&mut`-references, it is usually easier to make the code come to the data instead of making the data come to the code.